# Is it possible to rewrite the code so the time complexity is O(nlogn)?

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to find the maximum difference between two numbers in an array, the minuend has to be prior to the subtractor. For example: In An array (3,1,5,4,2), the maximum difference should be 3 (5-2). In an array (100, 3 ,200), the maximum difference should be 97(100-3).

```
int max = 0, diff;
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
  for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++){
    diff = D[i] - D[j];
    if(diff > max)
      max = diff;
  }
}
return max;
```

I know it has time complexity of `O(n^2)` but I want it to be exactly `O(nlogn)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traverse the array from the last element to the first.

Maintain two variables answer and mintillnow.

```
For each element i:

    answer=max(answer,i-mintillnow)    

    mintillnow=min(mintillnow,i)
```

Final answer can be found in `answer` at the end of the traversal.

Time Complexity :- O(n)

---

If for some reason you want it to be exactly O(log(n)):-

Maintain a Min Heap and an answer variable.

At each step,

Query the Min Heap for the smallest element till now and subtract it from the current element and check if this is larger than the answer variable.

Push the current element into the Min Heap.

Insertion into Min Heap takes O(log(n))

Querying for minimum takes O(1).

Total Time Complexity :- O(n log(n))

Comment: The current item should be the subtractor, swapping min with max solves everything.

Comment: Its mentioned that 'the minuend has to be prior to the subtractor'. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm traversing the array in reverse order. This I encounter the subtractor first and then the minuend. So i keep track of the minimum subtractor I've seen till now. Am i still missing something because now even I'm confused

Comment: You can also traverse from the beginning to the end and keep track of the maximum that you have seen till now. It would give the same answer

Comment: Sorry I must have skipped something and looked up the code directly. Your solution is 100% correct.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to find the maximum difference between any two numbers in an array.

Do you think that there is any way in which that difference could be higher than the difference between the minimum and the maximum number in the array? (I don't think so)

If there isn't, then you can write it in `O(n)`: just loop through the array once to find the minimum and maximum number; their difference should be the maximum difference.

Comment: The minuend has to be prior to the subtractor in the array. Is it possible to get exactly `O(nlogn)`?

Comment: To the downvoter: please check the edit time of the question and note that the question was changed after I provided my answer. It's always useful to do that before downvoting.

Answer (score -1):

Can you sort the array first? It would be o(nlgn). The diff between the first and the last would be the maximum diff?

```
Arrays.sort(D);
return D[D.length - 1] - D[0];
```